# Writing scripts in Jmeter to simulate http requests without using GUI

Tags: performance, http, automation, jmeter, load-testing

Is there a way to write scripts that simulate HTTP requests in JMeter. I know this can be done using the GUI, but is there a way to automate it using scripts?

Comment: You can do it only using GUI.

Comment: Non-GUI mode is for running JMeter scripts. GUI mode is for constructing them.

Comment: Of course you can edit JMX file manually, but you won't like it.

Comment: Oh...I am starting to get it, thank you. Again sorry if those questions seem trivial, i just started using JMeter today =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main method for writing JMeter scripts is using GUI. 
Another option is to edit manually JMX file but (almost) nobody uses it as:

- its format isn't documented (at least I haven't saw it)
- JMeter GUI is really easy to use. See [JMeter New GUI features to increase your productivity](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/ubikwiki/index.php?title=JMeter_New_GUI_features_to_increase_your_productivity). It can't be said about JMX XML file

Non-GUI mode is for running JMeter scripts (it takes less resources than GUI mode)